# overflow-x children element width

Tags: css, overflow

I have a div with overflow-x auto.
This div has children which are wider than the parent div, causing a scroll.

The inner children are given a border and background color which I would like to stretch across the entire width of them - including the scrolled overflow.
The actual content of the inner children is dynamic - so I can't give them a set width.

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">This is is row number 1</div>
  <div class="inner">This is is row number 2</div>
  <div class="inner">This is is row number 3</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it doesn't - as can be seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sL0rkjgm/), the background and border only stretch to the defined width of the parent.

How can I make the width of the children stretch to the entire scrolled area?

Comment: Your inner div have a width of 100px that they inherit from their parent.
What you see outside the red area is out of the divs, it t's simply text overflowing.
You may need to change your HTML to ensure the inner divs dictate their width, and the outer divs provides a viewport on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give `width` bigger than the outer to the inner, you'll have the result.

Try to give `width: 200px;` or `150%;` and let me know...

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:strech;
}

.inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="container-inner">
  <div class="inner">This is is row number 1</div>
  <div class="inner">This is is row number 2</div>
  <div class="inner">This is is rowfddfssdfdfs number 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is ok ?

Answer (score 3):

The `<div>` element is a `block` element and its width will be 100% of its parent. Making it an `inline` element will force the width of the `div` to stretch with its text content, but sadly it will need extra markup to make it break into rows (`<br/>` tags).

The way I manage to do it for your case is by making the inner container `display: table;` that way the element will behave as table and it'll stretch its width to match its inner text.

```
.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner {
  display: table;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here's a demo: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/74rhdwL3/)

Answer (score 1):

It is easy with jquery. Using jquery [scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth) you will the scroll width you can simply set that as width to inner div. So this will give you scroll width `$('.outer')[0].scrollWidth)` simply set this as width of inner div.

```js
$(".inner").css('width', $('.outer')[0].scrollWidth);
```

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">This is is row number 1</div>
  <div class="inner">This is is row number 2This is is row number 3 </div>
  <div class="inner">This is is row number 3 This is is row number 3 This is is row number 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

html: introducing an inner wrapper div

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="innerwrapper">
     <div class="inner">This is is row number 1</div>
    <div class="inner">This is is row number 2</div>
    <div class="inner">This is is row number 3 This is is row number 3 This is is row     number 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:stretch;
}

.innerwrapper {
   /* silence is golden */
}

.inner {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

linky: https://jsfiddle.net/sL0rkjgm/29/

Comment: This works because you added `display: flex` to the outer, not because of the inner wrapper div

Comment: it works because of both @Asher, without the inner wrapper div the inner divs don't stretch all of the way and there background colour doesn't stretch full width.